# Sails js One-to-Many Relationship with custom column names

Tags: sails.js, waterline

Faced serious problems here with Sails Js.
So, i have one-to-many relationship as described below (taken from official sails [documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/one-to-many)):

```
// myApp/api/models/User.js
// A user may have many pets
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    firstName: {
      type: 'string',
      columnName: "first_name"
    },
    lastName: {
      type: 'string',
      columnName: "last_name"
    },

    // Add a reference to Pets
    pets: {
      collection: 'pet',
      via: 'owner'
    }
  }
};
```

and dependent model:

```
// myApp/api/models/Pet.js
// A pet may only belong to a single user
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    breed: {
      type: 'string'
      //column name will be 'breed' by default
    },
    typeProperty: {
      type: 'string',
      columnName: "type_property"
    },
    nameProperty: {
      type: 'string',
      columnName: "name_property"
    },

    // Add a reference to User
    owner: {
      model: 'user'
    }
  }
};
```

When I'm calling in the code following query

```
User.find()
.populate('pets')
.exec(function(err, users) {
  if(err) // handle error

  // The users object would look something like the following
   [{
     id: 123,
     firstName: 'Foo',
     lastName: 'Bar',
     pets: [{
       id: 1,
       // !! Only this property is loaded !!
       breed: 'labrador',
       // !! This property is NOT loaded !!
       typeProperty: undefined,
       // !! This property is NOT loaded !!
       nameProperty: undefined,
       user: 123
     }]
   }]
});
```

Basically, seems that sails (waterline if to be specific) is not mapping back properties, which have custom "columName" specified and differs from property name (ex. "typeProperty" stored in `type_property` column).

Has anyone faced this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, I faced this problema. The property "columnName" is not working. Seems like Sails doesn't prioritizes this property over it's model's convention naming.

Try to change the model attribute name to be equal your database property.

```
type_property: {
  type: 'string'
},
```

this should make your attributes to be populated. Worked here.

**Column name works fine when the attribute in question is a foreign key.**

Comment: I want my code to be readable and don't want to renaim fields all over my code. For now I resolved this issue by writting custom promise, which acts simmilar to `.populate("collectionName")`, but prioritezes the column name field. Anyway, this is just a partial solution.